# In-App Purchases not Showing up in App Store

Tags: ios, app-store, in-app-purchase

For some reason, my app has been approved and all of my in-app purchases have been approved; however, for some reason, my app does not say "offers in-app purchases" below its name, and my app crashes when trying to load the in-app purchases. Would there be any reason why this is happening?

I had submitted it once before and it was rejected, but that was because i had "made for kids" checked. Could that have caused some problem?

Comment: When did you app get approved. It usually takes sometime to get update in app store. Wait for 24 hours and if you still dont see the in-app purchases then you can contact apple support.

Comment: It was approved about 90 minutes ago, but I don't remember this happening with my last app. Maybe there is a difference in processing time between in-app purchases and the actual application? I'll wait 24 hours and then I'll do that then.

Comment: I think so. Because my first app got posted and it is available in app store immediately. In my next update I updated my app to Universal app version 2.0. I was able to see that my app updated to version 2 but not as an universal app. It took 24 hours to see my app in appstore as a universal application.